# How to install (and run) postgresql on a machine that has mysql?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I got the package postgresql-8.4.9.tar.bz2 on the postgresql website and installed it following the instructions on the file INSTALL. But when we try to run it, it doesn't work and throws this error:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
```

I don't know, maybe it's because of some conflict with mysql. Does anybody know what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL and PostgreSQL can run just fine on the same server together. It sounds like you've already got one instance of Postgres running. Try a `ps ax | grep postmaster` or similar to determine if the server daemon process is already running.

Comment: It really was running! Killing it almost solved all the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that another process is listening on port 5432. Try running the following command:

```
 sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 5432
```

Comment: Yeah! This was basically the problem. Just needed to kill the process and change the permissions of the postgres directories and things got running. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jayme How did you kill the process found in the netstat command?

Comment: @dotsConnect I think I used this command: kill -9 `ps aux | grep -i 'postgres' | awk '{print $2}'` or something like. The netstat gives the process id you need. For example:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1201/postgres

kill -9 1201 solves it as well. ;)